# zsh: command not found: flutter

Tags: flutter, sdk, zshrc

I added the path in .zshrc file but it is still saying command not found, i tried 100 times but it is not working

my .zshrc file

[image: please see the image here]

my flutter folder path

[image: please see the image here]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: IF YOU TRIED EVERYTHING BUT STILL "COMMAND NOT FOUND", THEN DOWNLOAD THE SDK AGAIN AND DO THE SAME PROCESS. IT WILL WORK.

Comment: faced similar problem in linux, work with installing via git

Answer (score 2):

You need to add flutter bin folder to your path like this:

1- open terminal

2- Open paths file

```
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

3- Add Flutter bin path

```
YOUR_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY/flutter/bin
```

4- Restart terminal

Answer (score 0):

launch the terminal

Copy the following line and paste it
" `nano ~/.zshenv` "
(remove the quotes).

after it opens paste the line -
`export PATH=$HOME/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY/flutter/bin:$PATH`

then press `Ctrl x` then press `y` then press Return.
restart the terminal and write `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in `.zshenv` instead.
I always define a function in such files that adds the path and removes duplicates. You can then source the file without logging out and without dupilcating entrys.

```
addpath()      { # Add a folder to the PATH environment variable only if the folder exists and without duplicating it.
                   if [ -d "$1" ]; then export PATH="$1:$(echo $PATH | sed -e "s|$1:||g" -e "s|$1\$||" -e 's|::|:|g' -e 's|:$||')"; fi; }
```

You can then add a path using:

```
addpath /path/to/my/bin
```

zsh uses 4 different files to define stuff like this.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-do-zsh-configuration-files-work